# Creating Duplicate Subdirectories in Current Working Directory When Organizing Files Based on Categories

Tags: python

I am currently working on a script aimed at organizing files based on their extensions, categories, and subcategories. The objective is to move these files to designated subdirectories within a target directory, following a well-defined category and subcategory structure. However, I have encountered a perplexing issue: the script is inadvertently generating a duplicated copy of my current working directory (cwd) within the existing cwd, rather than correctly forming the intended subdirectory structure within the designated target directory.

Here's a Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE) that illustrates the situation (please note that `file`s would be a `List` of strings):

```py
import os
import shutil
from typing import List

def get_extension(file_name: str) -> str:
    return "." + file_name.split(".")[-1].lower()

TEXT_ = (".txt", ".rtf", ".md")
TARGET_DIR_ = "TestDIR"

file_extensions = {
    TEXT_: "Text",
}

def establish_current_dir() -> List[str]:
    try:
        os.chdir(TARGET_DIR_)
        current_dir = os.getcwd()
        files = os.listdir(current_dir)
        return files
    
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"{TARGET_DIR_} directory not found.")
        return []
    
def organize(files: List[str]) -> None:
  for file in files:
      extension = get_extension(file)
      for extensions, category in file_extensions.items():
          category_dir = category
          if extension in extensions:
              if extension in [".md"]:
                  subdir_name = "markdown"
          else:
            subdir_name = "foobar"
                  
      subcategory_dir = os.path.join(category_dir, subdir_name)

      if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR_, subcategory_dir)):
          os.makedirs(subcategory_dir)

      shutil.move(file, os.path.join(TARGET_DIR_, subcategory_dir, os.path.basename(file)))

files = establish_current_dir()
organize(files)
```

While I am new to the `os` library, I've reviewed documentation and deduced that the following code snippet is intended to create a new directory:

```
      if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR_, subcategory_dir)):
          os.makedirs(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR_, subcategory_dir))
```

However, the actual outcome is that a copy (subdirectory) of my `cwd` is created in the location where files should be sorted. Functionally, the script works as intended, sorting the files into categories, but into subdirectories rather than the main target directory.

I suspect that my usage of `os.makedirs(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR_, subcategory_dir))` might be causing the unintended duplication, essentially resulting in `TestDIR/TestDIR/Text`. I experimented with just `os.makedirs(os.path.join(subcategory_dir))`, but this modification did not resolve the issue.

I would greatly appreciate insights into what might be causing this behavior and suggestions for rectifying the problem. Thank you for your assistance!

**edit:**

I am using the `.chdir()` function from the `os` library to change the current directory to my `TARGET_DIR` and then grabbing all the files and storing them in a `List` of strings.

```py
def establish_current_dir() -> List[str]:
    try:
        os.chdir(TARGET_DIR_)
        current_dir = os.getcwd()
        files = os.listdir(current_dir)
        return files
    
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"{TARGET_DIR_} directory not found.")
        return []
```

Comment: What's the cwd of your script?

Comment: @Swifty I made an edit to the post, I hope this makes it easier. The script (`main.py`) is in the `Projects` dir. To my understanding, this shouldn't be an issue since the script is seeking the `TARGET_DIR`, and sorting the files in there. I could be wrong tho.

Comment: There's a problem with `subdir_name`: if your file is a `.txt` for example, this variable is not assigned anything, which causes `organize()` to raise an error; if you didn't encounter this, perhaps you assigned a value to it (in the console?) earlier. If I understand correctly, `.md` should be moved to /text/md; what should happen to other text files? And to files with 'unknown' (or rather unlisted) extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem came from the `subdir_name` variable being initialized (probably with 'TestDIR') somewhere outside your code; I reorganized your data into a more usable form, and rewrote the code (assuming files with unlisted extensions go into `foobar`):

```
import os
import shutil


def get_extension(file_name: str) -> str:
    return "." + file_name.split(".")[-1].lower()


category = {".txt": 'Text',
            ".rtf": 'Text',
            ".md": 'Text'}

subdir = {'.md': 'markdown'}

TARGET_DIR_ = "TestDIR"


def organize() -> None:
    for file in os.listdir(TARGET_DIR_):
        extension = get_extension(file)
        category_dir = category.get(extension, 'foobar')
        subdir_name = subdir.get(extension)

        file_target_dir = os.path.join(TARGET_DIR_, category_dir)
        if subdir_name:
            file_target_dir = os.path.join(file_target_dir, subdir_name)
        if not os.path.exists(file_target_dir):
                os.makedirs(file_target_dir)

        shutil.move(os.path.join(TARGET_DIR_, file), os.path.join(file_target_dir, os.path.basename(file)))


organize()
```

Testing with a few fake files, .txt and .rtf go into TestDIR/Text/, .md into TestDIR/Text/markdown and other files into TestDIR/foobar/

Comment: Thank you. I solved my issue by changing my `establish_current_dir` function. Using `os.scandir` and list concatenation over my original version seemed to resolve the issue. This is still a great answer, accepting and upvoting.